# ¿Cómo obtener todos los registros de la DB en String?

Tags: laravel, api

Cuando hago una consulta en Laravel, me retorna así:

```
{
  "ID":1,
  "Detalle":"es un detalle",
  "Precio":1.3
}
```

Pero yo necesito que me retorne todo en String, así:

```
{
  "ID":"1",
  "Detalle":"es un detalle",
  "Precio":"1.3"
}
```

¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo? Es para una api.

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es que en tu modelo agregues el array `$cast['id' => 'string',  precio => 'string']`

Comment: si, muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Versión original del hilo de SO ingles:

> Attribute Casting The $casts property on your model provides a
> convenient method of converting attributes to common data types. The
> $casts property should be an array where the key is the name of the
> attribute being cast and the value is the type you wish to cast the
> column to. The supported cast types are integer, real, float, double,
> decimal:, string, boolean, object, array, collection, date, datetime,
> and timestamp. When casting to decimal, you must define the number of
> digits (decimal:2).

Traducida de un hilo de SO versión ingles:

> La propiedad `$casts` en tu modelo proporciona un método conveniente
> para la conversión de atributos a tipo de datos comunes. Además
> `$casts` debe ser un un array donde la llave es el nombre del
> atributo y el valor, el tipo de dato al cual sera casteado. Los tipos
> de datos que soporta el array `$casts` son:
> `integer`,`real`,`float`,`double`, `string`, `boolean`, `object`,
> `array`, `collection`, `date`, `datetime` y `timestamp`

En código seria algo así:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Foo extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
protected $casts = [
    'id' => 'string',
    'precio' => 'string'
];
```

Te dejo la doc de laravel donde puedes encontrar más info al respecto.
[Mutators and Casting Laravel 8](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators)

[Hilo en ingles de donde saque la respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63471965/how-to-cast-string-into-int-in-laravel-model)

Comment: Seria bueno que agregaras la respuesta en ingles que traduces, ademas de cambiar "gringa" por "ingles"

Comment: Listo, he agregado la información que faltaba

Comment: si, muchas gracias

Comment: @JoseEspinalLuque recuerda marcar en la palomita si te sirvio la respuesta